# mysqldump ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jaimemontoya'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to clone a MySQL database by using `root@jaimemontoya:~# mysqldump -u jaimemontoya -pMyPasswordHere original_db | mysql -u jaimemontoya -pMyPasswordHere cloned_db`. I am getting this error:

```
mysqldump: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'jaimemontoya'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jaimemontoya'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My password is correct. Is the problem related to granting permissions to my user to run `mysqldump`, or is it something else?

Comment: access denied for password problem means a problem with the user configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this on a MySQL Managed Database. So I specified the corresponding connection to that database and could export it successfully:

```
root@jaimemontoya:/var/www# mysqldump -u jaimemontoya -pMyPasswordHere -h [name_here].ondigitalocean.com -P [port_number_here] original_db > cloned_db.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database. If you don't want to restore GTIDs, pass --set-gtid-purged=OFF. To make a complete dump, pass --all-databases --triggers --routines --events.
Warning: A dump from a server that has GTIDs enabled will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that were executed during its extraction and might not be represented in the dumped data. This might result in an inconsistent data dump.
In order to ensure a consistent backup of the database, pass --single-transaction or --lock-all-tables or --master-data.
root@mfh-elsalvador:/var/www# ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          8793157 Oct 29 10:29 cloned_db.sql
```